# Inherited std::array and aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, aggregate-initialization

I have a need to compare triplets of doubles that were calculated using different processes which causes them to differ by small amounts but should be considered equivalent. One approach that appears to work is to inherit `std::array` in such a way that the values can be compared within some delta of each other. This appears to work:

```
template <int precision_equals = 4> // default equal test precision is .1^4 (.0001)
class RGB : public std::array<double,3>
```

I also need to interop with standard  arrays which requires a conversion constructor. However, it appears aggregate initialization is not allowed when a constructor is provided: [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

*no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed)*

But I have added this constructor which is needed when assigning from a regular array like `b2 = a;` in the code:

```
    RGB(const std::array<double,3>& x) {*static_cast<std::array<double,3>*>(this) = x;}
```

Yet, this seems to work.

```
RGB<2> b2{{ 1,2,3 }};
```

Is this not aggregate initialization? Am I missing something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::array;
using std::cout;

template <int precision_equals = 4> // default equal test precision is .1^4 (.0001)
class RGB : public std::array<double,3>
{
public:
    RGB(const std::array<double,3>& x) {*static_cast<std::array<double,3>*>(this) = x;}
    friend bool operator==(const RGB& a, const RGB& b)
    {
        auto resolution = [](int prec)
        {
            double factor = 1.0;
            while (prec--)
                factor = factor / 10.0;
            return factor;
        };
        constexpr double delta = resolution(precision_equals);
        return a[0] < b[0] + delta && a[0] > b[0] - delta
            && a[1] < b[1] + delta && a[1] > b[1] - delta
            && a[2] < b[2] + delta && a[2] > b[2] - delta;
    }
    friend bool operator!=(const RGB& a, const RGB& b) { return !(a == b); }
};


int main()
{
    // shows vector of inherited arrays can be sorted
    vector<RGB<2>> v{ {{1,2.0001,3}}, {{1,2,3}} };
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    array<double, 3> a{ 1,2,3 };

    RGB<2> b2{{ 1,2,3 }};
    RGB<2> c2{{ 1.001,2,3 }};
    RGB<3> b3{{ 1,2,3 }};
    RGB<3> c3{{ 1.005,2,3 }};

    // comparisons work
    cout << "b2==c2: " << (b2 == c2 ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    cout << "b3==c3: " << (b3 == c3 ? "true\n" : "false\n");

    // assignments to/from regular arrays work
    a = b2;
    b2 = a;
}
```

Works in MSVC and GCC.  [Link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/85Mc1z)

@LanguageLawyer notes that an assignment conversion operator would remove most of the need for a conversion constructor. Removal of the conversion constructor and replacement by this

```
    RGB& operator=(const std::array<double, 3>& from)
    {
        //return *this = *static_cast<const RGB*>(&from);  // UB

        (*this)[0] = from[0]; // ugly version that's not UB
        (*this)[1] = from[1];
        (*this)[2] = from[2];
        return *this;
    }
```

allows the code to compile so my use case is solved. However, the question whether the conversion constructor prohibits aggregate initialization remains.

Comment: Can you indicate on which line you think aggregate-initialization is happening?

Comment: You assume "curly braces == aggregate initialization". Therein is the misunderstanding.

Comment: @cigien Aren't all of the lines like this:`RGB<2> b2{{ 1,2,3 }};` aggregate initializations?

Comment: No, they're not. See StoryTeller's comment. This question is a little tricky to answer because of all the code you've shown. Trim it down to a few lines, since that's really all you need to ask your question.

Comment: Then what are they? `std::array` supposedly has no user constructors.

Comment: `std::array` does have a constructor, though it's implicit. And it does follow aggregate-initialization rules, that much is true. Again, to avoid a lengthy discussion in comments, edit your question to only ask what you just asked in the comments.

Comment: I don't think public inheritance of `std::array` is a good design choice. It doesn't make your class an aggregate automatically. I would favor *composition* rather than inheritance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  That's my preference as well. But this works quite well without the code bloat required to conform to stl containers and doesn't add state to `std::array` but more like a trait that only alters equality tests. Concern is that it actually shouldn't work by voiding aggregate initialization.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer. That's actually what I normally do. But I'd like to add an automatic mechanism to check against close floats.  The conversion constructor is needed for this line: `b2 = a;` `a = b2` is built in as the assignment operator returns a reference and there is no slicing since no additional state.

Comment: You don't need conversion constructor for this, you need to add assignment and conversion operators from/to (reference to) `std::array` in your class. Unlike conversion constructor, they won't affect that the inherited class is an aggregate.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Agreed. Seems like a good approach and avoids the restriction on aggregate initialization.

Comment: _assignment and conversion operators_ Well, only assignment, because one doesn't need a conversion operator to convert to a public base class >_<

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a language lawyer question. Are you sure that quotes from the standard will be helpful for you?

Comment: `static_cast<const RGB*>(&from)` is [U](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#11.sentence-4)[B](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#11.sentence-5).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  If I declare the assignment operator constexpr I can initialize this `constexpr RGB<2> b2{ 1,2,3 };` Compiler is suppose to guarantee that is not UB. Compiler bug?

Comment: `constexpr RGB<2> b2{ 1,2,3 };` doesn't use the assignment operator.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Right. Will check properly.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yep. UB. revised.

Answer (score 0):

Calling base constructor should be better

Untested code

```cpp
    RGB(const std::array<double,3>& x) : std::array<double, 3>(x) {}
```

or a slight rewrite

```cpp
using BaseRGB = std::array<double,3>;
template <int precision_equals = 4> // default equal test precision is .1^4 (.0001)
class RGB : public BaseRGB {
public:
    RGB(const BaseRGB& x) : BaseRGB(x) {}

    // or even
    using BaseRGB::BaseRGB; // using the constructor directly if you don't set up anything more.
```

Comment: Using `using BaseRGB::BaseRGB` works well and is necessary doing a similar thing with where BaseRGB is `vector<double>` since it isn't an aggregate type. I also have a use case for that. But `array<double,3>` is an aggregate type according to cppreference. In any case, language-lawyer's comment to use an assignment operator works and allows removal of the conversion constructor so the inherited class is still an aggregate type.